# Фильтрация по выбранной радиокнопке yii2

Tags: php, yii2

Есть три радиокнопки и кнопка submit
в контроллере есть условия типа если выбран такой то чекбокс,то выводи из базы данных цену товаров  диапазоне от 0-10,если такой то 10-30 и тп. 
Как мне передать в контроллер то, что выбрана конкретная радиокнопка,и чтобы выполнялось конкретно ее условие при нажатии на submit?

Comment: может код покажите?

Comment: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/718789/%D0%A4%D0%B8%D0%BB%D1%8C%D1%82%D1%80%D0%B0%D1%86%D0%B8%D1%8F-yii2-%D0%B2%D1%8B%D0%B4%D0%B0%D0%B5%D1%82-%D0%BE%D1%88%D0%B8%D0%B1%D0%BA%D1%83-call-to-a-member-function-isattributerequired-on