# Фильтрация yii2 выдает ошибку Call to a member function isAttributeRequired() on null

Tags: php, yii2, фильтрация

Пытаюсь сделать фильтрацию на yii2. Есть поле формы в ней 3      `input(type="radio")`, каждый инпут должен искать товары с ценой в данном диапазоне.

Код контроллера где выполняется поиск:

```
public function actionFilter()
        {
            $filter = trim(Yii::$app->request->get('filter'));
            $this->setMeta('MAC-SHOPPER | ' . $filter);
            if (!$filter) {
                return $this->render('filter');
            }
/*
            if ($filter <= 15) {

            $query = Product::find()->where(['<=', 'price', 15]);
            }*/

            $model = new Product();

            if($Button1) {
                $query = Product::find()->where(['between', 'price', "0", "50" ])->all();
            }
            //Создаем объект класса Pagination
            //Передаем тотал каунт - общее количество записей, которыe мы вытащим
            $pages = new Pagination(['totalCount' => $query->count(), 'pageSize' => 2, 'forcePageParam' => false, 'pageSizeParam' => false]);
            //Выполняем сам запрос
            //offset - с какой записи начинать
            //limit - количество записей
            $products = $query->offset($pages->offset)->limit($pages->limit)->all();
            return $this->render('filter', compact('products', 'pages', 'filter', 'model'));
        }
```

Модель товара:

```
<?php
    namespace app\models;
    use yii\db\ActiveRecord;
    //класс для таблицы категории
    class Product extends ActiveRecord
    {
        public $Button1;
        public $Button2;
        public $Button3;
        public $radioButtonList;


        //Поведение для картинок
             public function behaviors()
        {
            return [
                'image' => [
                    'class' => 'rico\yii2images\behaviors\ImageBehave',
                ]
            ];
        }




        public static function tableName()
        {
            return 'product';
        }

        public function getCategory()
        {
            //Связь таблиц, один продукт может иметь одну категорию (hasOne()) 
            return $this->hasOne(Category::className(), ['id' => 'category_id']);
        }



    }
?>
```

Сама форма:

```
<?php $form = ActiveForm::begin([
                                'id' => 'task-form',
                                'action' => \yii\helpers\Url::to(['category/filter']),
                                ]  
                                )?>





                         <?= $form->field($model, 'radioButtonList')
                                ->radioList([
                                    'Button1' => 'от 0-1500',     
                                    'Button2' => 'от 3000-5000',
                                    'Button3' => 'от 5000-20000'
                                ],[
                                    'id' => 'radio_button',

                                ]); ?>
                            <?= Html::submitButton('Найти', ['class' => 'btn btn-success']);?>
                        <?php $form = ActiveForm::end() ?>
```

Как мне поместить в свойства `$Button1`, `$Button2`, `$Button3` `price` из таблицы товаров, чтобы при клике на определенный инпут он выводил товары как сделано в условии контроллера(то есть по диапазону цены)

Comment: что это вообще за переменные? Зачем вы их создали? У вас есть поле `radioButtonList` вы пытались заглянуть в него после отправки формы?

Answer (score 0):

Значит, идем в [документацию](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc-2.0/yii-bootstrap-activefield.html#radioList()-detail), видим:

> The data item used to generate the radio buttons. The array values are the labels, while the array keys are the corresponding radio values.

Значит, `radioList` первым параметром, ожидает от вас, массив где ключи это ЗНАЧЕНИЯ инпута, а значения массива - это labels (этикетка/описание).

Собственно, если вы загляните в html, что выходит из вашего кода:

```
$form->field($model, 'radioButtonList')
->radioList([
    'Button1' => 'от 0-1500',     
    'Button2' => 'от 3000-5000',
    'Button3' => 'от 5000-20000'
]);
```

То увидите примерно:

```
<label>от 0-1500</label>
<input  type="radio" value="Button1" name="radioButtonList"/>

<label>от 3000-5000</label>
<input type="radio" value="Button2" name="radioButtonList"/>

<label>от 5000-20000</label>
<input type="radio" value="Button3" name="radioButtonList"/>
```

Что будет если запостить такую форму? Ну к примеру постом? Что получите?

Вы получите в переменой `$_POST` по ключу `radioButtonList` значение `Button1`, `Button2` или `Button3`.

И как же нам получить значение?

Из массива на прямую - `$_POST['radioButtonList']`

Через метод фреймворка - `Yii::$app->request->post('radioButtonList')`

Загрузить в модель -

```
$model = new Product();
if($model->load(Yii::$app->request->post())){
   ... $model->radioButtonList;
}
```

Пока, ваш контроллер это сплошной набор строк кода, который даже связать в голове не выходит, даже описывать не хочу. Просто укажу вам, что по умолчанию, ваша форма будет слать `POST` запрос.

Причина ваших проблем (мне кажется, что та же причина, почему вам не хотят помогать тут) - вам стоит изучить документацию, и повторить примеры которые в ней. Это вообще как минимум. (хотя бы - [ссылка](https://yiiframework.com.ua/ru/doc/guide/)).